# Как очистить лист excel средствами Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Как правильнее очистить лист в `excel` средствами `Python`, использую библиотеку `openpyxl`.
Сейчас у меня такой код, который 10 тысяч ячеек заполняет пустыми строками, это занимает некоторое время и как будто костыльный вариант, как это сделать правильнее?

```py
import openpyxl
def clear_shit(shit_name):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('results.xlsx')
    sheet = wb[shit_name]
    for i in range(2, 10000):
        for cellObj in sheet[f'A{i}':f'AZ{i}']:
            for cell in cellObj:
                sheet[cell.coordinate] = ''
    self.wb.save('results.xlsx')
```

Comment: Возможно ли, что Вам надо: `wb.worksheets["name"].clear()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось очистить лист методом удаления столбцов (или если нужно строк):

```
import openpyxl

def clear_shit(shit_name):

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='results.xlsx')
    sheet = wb[shit_name]
    sheet.delete_cols(0, 100)
    wb.save('results.xlsx')
```

и еще один совет от создателя openpyxl Charlie Clark, что вы всегда можете удалить лист и создать новый с тем же именем (цитирую на память, недословно).